# How to add the connected SQL Server database to the solution folder?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I've created a small ASP.NET MVC application and used a SQL Server database. I saw that the database was not moved to the *Solution folder*, so if understood correctly, the application won't work on other computers/servers.

Is it possible to move somehow the database to the project without losing the connection with the application?

Please help! Thanks in advance!

Answer:

The problem was solved with the solution from

https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/441590/How-to-add-existing-database-in-app-data-folder-in

Comment: Is this a "localdb" database? We need a bit more detail. Normally localdb is only used for development, for live use you'd want to deploy the database to an instance of SQL Server.

Comment: Normallly, you install your database on a server, and the users connect to it. Unless you want that every single user connect on it's own local copy of a databse? You still gonna need to install a instance of Sql server; you could use SQL express in that case ?

Comment: This is my first application with a database. I've created the database using Sql Server Studio Management and connected it by ADO.NET

Comment: I have the application on a github repository and I want the database also be in there, so it would work for everyone who's accessing the repository

Comment: Ok so if you mean you want the database _code_ to be in the repo, then you need you generate the "CREATE" SQL scripts which would be used to set up the database. SQL Management Studio can help you do this. Anyone in posession of those scripts would be able to generate a new database with the same design inside their own instance of SQL Server. The database is not part of your ASP.NET application, it's a separate service, so it isn't part of your .NET project.

Comment: What you _can_ do to make this process easier is use a Database Project in Visual Studio (which you can add to your Solution alongside the MVC project), which can hold SQL scripts, and interact with database to generate and deploy the scripts. And then these scripts can be source-controlled in your git repository. See https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/create-sql-server-database-project-with-visual-studio/ and https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/features/ssdt/

Comment: FYI Please don't mark questions as "Solved". That's not how this site works, it's not a forum. If you have a solution, please add it as an Answer in the section below. Answering your own questions is allowed and encouraged. That way, people can upvote your solution and also, questions with accepted or populate answers will show higher in search results when people search for similar things. I've rolled back your "Solved" edit so you can go ahead and write an answer instead. Thanks.

Comment: @ADyson Thank you very much for your answers! I was in lack of time, so I just used the solution provided by codeproject.com and I refactored my models

Answer (score 2):

No. Seriously. ANY serious setup will have a database server and somone will apply a backup of the database you provide there. Unless you write toy applications, you NEVER employ the databsae on the same machine and "in the folder" - this works for development, it is not how SQL is deployed in the real world of larger controlled applications.

And get used on how to make upgrades to that database via some sort of change script mechanism.